# Quick way to isolate layer and hide others in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Similar to how CAD works, is there a way to quickly hide all other layers than the one you are working on?

Working on QGIS 2.18 on mac

Comment: Please have a look at this [link](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#layers-panel). The **Manage visibility** option should be useful for your task.

Comment: @nash You should post an answer to explain the manipulation. It's a good answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can :

- Select the group of layers you need to switch
- Group all the layers by right clicking on them

[image: Exclusive 1]

- use the Mutually Exclusive option : **it allows only one layer activated in the group.**

[image: Exclusive 2]

After that, you click on the box of one layer and it deactivates all the others.
You can click another and it will automatically deactivate the previous one.

[image: Exclusive 3]

[image: Exclusive 4]

Comment: That is very handy and just what i was looking for, thank you!